# matching the arrays react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

This may be a silly question.

I'm creating a dashboard and as a first step, i used dummy hard-coded values to build the dashboard. after that, I got data from API and now I want to use data from API instead of using hard-coded data.

[image]

Expanded the API array:

[image]
API array represents data from API and hardcoded array represents data from hard coded data. as you can see, the array format differs from API to hardcoded. instead of array inside array can we have the data format the same as in a hardcoded array(just values only)?

```
const hardcoded = [
    [118, 1, 2, 3, 100, 2, 10, 108],
    [3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5],
    [10, 4, 2, 12, 45, 356],
    [8, 1, 2, 3, 1],
    [3, 1, 1, 100],
    [10, 491, 2],
];

const dataFromApi1 = lostRecoveryInfo?.map(
    ({ lost, recoveryTimespan, netLost, netRecovered }) => [
        lost,
        recoveryTimespan?.map(({ count }) => count),

        netLost,
        netRecovered,
    ],
);

console.log("------------------->API", dataFromApi1);
console.log("------------------->hardcoded", hardcoded);
```

Current data format from API and expected data format from API are given below:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to filter out the second element in the API response array items?

Comment: Hi i updated the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
yourApiData.map(x=>x.flat())
```

You can take a look at the docs on the funtions [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
yourApiData = [
    [118, [1, 2, 3, 100, 2], 10, 108],
    [3, [1, 1, 1, 3], 4, 5],
    [10, [4, 2, 12], 45, 356],
    [8, [1, 2], 3, 1],
    [3, [1], 1, 100],
    [10, [], 491, 2],
]
console.log(yourApiData.map(x=>x.flat()))
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion is to try to replace the underscores/spaces/quotes using replace(). e.g.

```
const newData = key.replace("argument to be replaced", "value to replace argument");
console.log(newData);
```

I hope this was helpful.